# Skewness difference in empirical distribution

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, skewness

Is there a test to see if skewness of two empirical distributions are significantly different from one another?

Comment: You can look for significant differences using resampling methods. You might also consider looking for stochastic dominance if you're interesting in one skewness being larger than another without regard to differences explicitly.

Comment: @statwoman  Are you interested in a *specific* skewness coefficient or might one do as well as another? What would one group having larger skewness tell you?